# How to make 123456789 from image as a dynamic variable in Jmeter

Tags: soap, automation, jmeter, blazemeter

I have my XML Body data (attached screenshot below),

From screenshot you can see value `123456789` in Signature.

I'm looking to make `123456789` a dynamic variable value, So that JMeter automatically gets that value from server whenever I run script.

I'm looking something like Regular expression extractor but for SOAP request.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you add the **text** of response?

Answer (score 2):

You can add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with values:

```
Reference Name: aSignature

Regular expression: (\d+)</aSignature> 

Template: $1$ 

Match No: 1
```

You'll get First match of all numbers before `aSignature` end tag.

It'll save value in a variable you can use later as `${aSignature}` (or vars.get("aSignature") in JSR223 component)

Using Regular expression is better than using XPath according to [jmeter mailing](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/Which-is-quot-better-quot-XPath-v-s-Regular-Expression-Extractor-td534742.html), [ubik](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/) and [testautomationguru](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. What if my value also have letter in it?

Comment: Just change expression to `(\w+)</aSignature>` which include digits and letters

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time. I am still getting an error premature end of file in log view.

Comment: Hi, What will be my expression if my variable contains special characters, numbers and letters? How to declare that? is it (\w+)</aSignature> for special characters too?

Comment: Try ([^\t]+)</aSignature>

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of your request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `signature`
   - XPath Expression: `//*[local-name()='aSignature']/text()`
3. Refer the extracted value as `${signature}` where required.

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath 1.0 Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [XPath `local-name()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time. I am still getting an error premature end of file in log view.

Comment: This indicates incomplete response so I guess extraction won't make a lot of sense

Comment: So is there anything else I can try?